# Is this interpretation of the EM algorithm correct?

Tags: expectation-maximization

Suppose we want to estimate the parameter $\theta$ of the distribution $p(z;\theta)$ of a random variable $Z$. If we had the i.i.d samples $z_1, z_2, \dots, z_N$, we could easily do this using maximum likelihood estimation. However, suppose we are only given the samples $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N$ of another random variable $X$, where $X$ and $Z$ are related via the joint distribution $p(x,z)$. Since $p(x,z) = p(x \mid z) \cdot p(z;\theta)$, then $p(x,z) = p(x,z;\theta)$.

The objective of the EM algorithm is to estimate the samples $z_1, z_2, \dots, z_N$ using the given samples $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N$, and then use these estimated samples to perform maximum likelihood estimation to estimate $\theta$. However, it turns out that estimating the samples $z_1, z_2, \dots, z_N$ using the samples $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N$ requires knowledge of $\theta$, which is what we are trying to estimate in the first place. Therefore, we initialize a value for $\theta$, estimate the samples $z_1, z_2, \dots, z_N$, then estimate a new value for $\theta$, and repeat the process until convergence.

More formally, if
$$
p(z_1, z_2, \dots, z_N;\theta)
$$
is the likelihood function for $\theta$, then to maximize this likelihood function, we need to estimate the samples $z_1, z_2, \dots, z_N$ as $\hat{z}_1, \hat{z}_2, \dots, \hat{z}_N$ such that
$$
\hat{z}_i = \mathbb{E}[Z \mid x_i] \quad \forall i \in \{1,2,\dots,N\}
$$
We could then plug these estimates into the likelihood function,
$$
p(\hat{z}_1, \hat{z}_2, \dots, \hat{z}_N;\theta)
$$
to determine $\theta$. However, as each $\hat{z}_i$ depends on $\theta$, we need to use the iterative process mentioned above.

Is this interpretation correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kind of half right. Obviously the main objective is to estimate $\theta$ from $x$. Given knowledge of $z$, we can maximise the likelihood derived from $p(z;\theta)$. This is done in the M-step. What is computed in the E-step is the expected value of that likelihood given $x$ and the $\theta$ estimated in the earlier M-step (or, in the beginning, its initial value). This amounts in some sense to the "estimation" of $z_1,\ldots,z_N$, as $x$ is known and $z$ is treated as random in $p(z;\theta)$. However, in most cases it isn't really estimating the individual observations as $\hat z_1,\ldots,\hat z_N$ and then plugging them in. For example, in mixture models, where $Z=(X,Y)$ and $Y$ is the mixture component to which an observation belongs (out of components $\{1,\ldots,K\}$, say), what is done is that the probabilities $P\{Y_i=k|x_i;\theta\}$ are estimated, i.e., a vector of $K$ conditional probabilities, rather than just a single $\hat y_i$ (or $\hat z_i$ by implication). Ultimately it depends on the form of the likelihood of $p(z;\theta)$ what exactly is done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Two questions: (1) Although the process that I mentioned is not exactly the EM algorithm, is there anything wrong with it? That is, can it be used in practice, and does it have a name other than "EM algorithm"? (2) Is the motivation for the EM algorithm that I mentioned accurate? That is, we use the EM algorithm when we want to estimate a parameter of a distribution $p(z;\theta)$, but we are only given samples of another random variable $X$, where $X$ and $Z$ are related by $p(x,z;\theta)$.

Comment: sure no problem. Would appreciate your feedback on this later.

Comment: A third misunderstanding is that $\hat Z=\mathbb E_\eta[Z|X+x]$ is not always the correct update in the E-step, i.e.$$\mathbb E_\eta[\log p(Z,x;\theta)|X=x]\ne \log p(\mathbb E_\eta[Z|X=x],x;\theta)$$

Comment: @Xi'an I am guessing then that $$\mathbb E_\eta[\log p(Z|x,\theta)]$$ is used in the E-step because it is guaranteed to be a lower-bound on the marginal likelihood $\log p(x)$ unlike $$\log p(\mathbb E_\eta[Z|X=x]|x,\theta)$$ correct?

Comment: @mhdadk first comment: Well, this depends on the definition of "wrong". Lloyd's K-means algorithm (as opposed to the EM for mixtures) works about as you describe it. That's a well established algorithm, however I don't think there's a guarantee that what you describe will converge in general or estimate the right thing (K-means is known to be biased as estimator for mixture parameters). This would need to be investigated for the specific situation you have in mind.

Comment: @mhdadk second question: That sounds about right, but you have defined $z$ in such a way that it contains all information about $x$, so $p(x,z;\theta)=p(z;\theta)$, and in general $x=T(z)$ where $T$ specifies how the information in $z$ is reduced in $x$. (I believe by the way that $y=(x,z),\ T(y)=x$ is more standard as notation for the EM-algorithm, which had me confused earlier.)

Comment: Thinking about this again, chances are this can be done also if not $x=T(z)$ and $p(x,z;\theta)=p(z;\theta)$, although I haven't seen an instance of this.

Comment: @ChristianHennig thanks a lot for your help! One last question: the standard expression used in the E-step, which is something like $\mathbb{E}[\log p(x,z) \mid x]$ is used because it is a lower-bound for the marginal log-likelihood $\log p(x)$, and so maximizing it will maximize the marginal log-likelihood, right? I think this is why my expression wouldn't work, because there is no guarantee that it is a lower-bound for the marginal log-likelihood.

Comment: @mhdadk I don't think that it's a lower bound of $\log p(x)$ in general, and even if it is, maximising a lower bound of a function doesn't maximise the function itself. I'm not aware of any "lower bound" argument in the derivation of the EM-algorithm. (There's a so-called MM-algorithm where maximisation of a lower bound occurs.)

Comment: @ChristianHennig [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm#Proof_of_correctness) is where I got the lower-bound argument from. [Here](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes2021fall/cs229-notes8.pdf) is another paper that mentions the lower-bound argument.

Comment: OK, fair enough, it's in the proof of convergence, not in the E-step itself. (It doesn't use that $\log p(x)$ is maximised; rather it's just improved, that's enough.)

Answer (score 0):

The main misconception in my question is that we are **not** trying to estimate $\theta$ as a parameter for $p(z;\theta)$, but we are trying to estimate $\theta$ as a parameter for $p(x,z;\theta)$. More precisely, we originally want to estimate $\theta$ as a parameter for $p(x;\theta)$, but if some of the data that we need to do this is missing, then we can split $p(x;\theta)$ into $p(x,z;\theta)$, where $z$ represents the missing values. Therefore, the main motivation for the EM algorithm is to deal with the missing data that is needed to estimate $\theta$. See the paper [A Gentle Tutorial of the EM Algorithm and its Application to Parameter Estimation for Gaussian Mixture and Hidden Markov Models](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.28.613) by Jeff Bilmes, 1998, for more details.

---

To add to @ChristianHennig's answer, consider the case where the joint distribution of $X$ and $Z$ is a bivariate normal distribution with parameters $\mu_X,\sigma_X^2,\mu_Z,\sigma_Z^2,$ and $\rho$, where
$$
\rho = \frac{\text{Cov}(X,Z)}{\sqrt{\sigma_X^2 \sigma_Z^2}}
$$
is the correlation coefficient. This means that
$$
p(x,z) = \frac{1}{2\pi \sigma_X \sigma_Z \sqrt{1 - \rho^2}} \cdot \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[\left(\frac{x - \mu_X}{\sigma_X}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{z - \mu_Z}{\sigma_Z}\right)^2 - 2\rho \frac{(x - \mu_X)(z - \mu_Z)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Z} \right]\right)
$$
In the E-step of the EM algorithm, the conditional expectation
$$
\mathbb{E}[\log p(x,Z) \mid x]
$$
with respect to $Z$ is computed. Since
$$
\log p(X,Z) = -\log \left(2\pi \sigma_X \sigma_Z \sqrt{1 - \rho^2}\right) -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[\left(\frac{X - \mu_X}{\sigma_X}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{Z - \mu_Z}{\sigma_Z}\right)^2 - 2\rho \frac{(X - \mu_X)(Z - \mu_Z)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Z} \right]
$$
then
$$
\mathbb{E}[\log p(x,Z) \mid x] = -\log \left(2\pi \sigma_X \sigma_Z \sqrt{1 - \rho^2}\right) -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[\left(\frac{x - \mu_X}{\sigma_X}\right)^2 + \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\frac{Z - \mu_Z}{\sigma_Z}\right)^2 \mid x\right] - 2\rho \frac{(x - \mu_X)(\mathbb{E}[Z \mid x] - \mu_Z)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Z} \right]
$$
Since $(\cdot)^2$ is a convex function, then by Jensen's inequality,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\frac{Z - \mu_Z}{\sigma_Z}\right)^2 \mid x\right] \geq \left(\frac{\mathbb{E}[Z \mid x] - \mu_Z}{\sigma_Z}\right)^2
$$
and so
$$
\mathbb{E}[\log p(x,Z) \mid x] \leq -\log \left(2\pi \sigma_X \sigma_Z \sqrt{1 - \rho^2}\right) -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[\left(\frac{x - \mu_X}{\sigma_X}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\mathbb{E}[Z \mid x] - \mu_Z}{\sigma_Z}\right)^2 - 2\rho \frac{(x - \mu_X)(\mathbb{E}[Z \mid x] - \mu_Z)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Z} \right]
$$
Note that
$$
\log p(x,\mathbb{E}[Z \mid x]) = -\log \left(2\pi \sigma_X \sigma_Z \sqrt{1 - \rho^2}\right) -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[\left(\frac{x - \mu_X}{\sigma_X}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\mathbb{E}[Z \mid x] - \mu_Z}{\sigma_Z}\right)^2 - 2\rho \frac{(x - \mu_X)(\mathbb{E}[Z \mid x] - \mu_Z)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Z} \right]
$$
and so
$$
\mathbb{E}[\log p(x,Z) \mid x] \leq \log p(x,\mathbb{E}[Z \mid x])
$$
which means that $\log p(x,\mathbb{E}[Z \mid x])$ is an upper-bound for $\mathbb{E}[\log p(x,Z) \mid x]$ in the case of a bivariate normal distribution. **However**, there is no guarantee that $\log p(x,\mathbb{E}[Z \mid x])$ is a lower-bound for $\log p(x)$, and so increasing $\log p(x,\mathbb{E}[Z \mid x])$ does not imply that $\log p(x)$ increases.

Furthermore, the proposed algorithm in the original question can be implemented for the bivariate normal distribution case, but it will not converge. Here is an implementation in Python:

```py
import numpy as np

# initialize random number generator
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed = 42)

# mean vector
mu = np.array([1,2])

# covariance matrix
sigma = np.array([[3,0],
                  [0,5]])

# number of samples
N = 1000

# observed (x) and unobserved (z) samples
x,z = rng.multivariate_normal(mu,sigma,N).T

# initial guesses for the mean vector and covariance matrix. Note that
# sigma_hat is matrix-multiplied by its transpose to ensure it is
# symmetric and positive definite
mu_hat = mu + rng.standard_normal(mu.shape) * 0.1
sigma_hat = sigma + rng.standard_normal(sigma.shape) * 0.1
sigma_hat = sigma_hat.T @ sigma_hat

# the complete dataset. The first column consists of all the observed
# samples of x. The second column consists of initial guesses of z
Y = rng.standard_normal((N,2))
Y[:,0] = x

for _ in range(100):
    # correlation coefficient estimate
    rho_hat = sigma_hat[0,1] / np.sqrt(sigma_hat[0,0] * sigma_hat[1,1])
    
    # estimates of z's
    Y[:,1] = mu_hat[1] + rho_hat * sigma_hat[1,1] * ((Y[:,0] - mu_hat[0])/sigma_hat[0,0])
    
    # estimate of mean vector
    mu_hat = Y.mean(axis = 0)
    
    # estimate of covariance matrix
    sigma_hat = (Y - mu_hat).T @ (Y - mu_hat) / Y.shape[0]
```